# ¿Cómo relacionar una subconsulta que utiliza UNION con otra tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito un empujón con esta consulta. Funciona perfectamente, pero no se como hacer que, utilizando el campo `idOT`, comprobar el campo `idOT` en otra tabla y traer un campo en concreto de esa tabla, que evidentemente coincida con `idOT`, y  para obtener el siguiente Resultado:

```
idOT........FIELD_1.....FIELD_2......CampodeOtraTabla.
```

la consulta es esta:

```
SELECT idOT, SUM(`FIELD_1`),SUM(`FIELD_2`) 
FROM (
(SELECT idOT, SUM(`horaspreparacion`.`Horas`) AS `FIELD_1` , 
        SUM(`horaspreparacion`.`HorasX`) AS `FIELD_2` 
        FROM `horaspreparacion`)
 UNION 
(SELECT idOT, SUM(`horasimprimacion`.`Horas`) AS `FIELD_1`, 
        SUM(`horasimprimacion`.`HorasX`) AS `FIELD_2` 
        FROM `horasimprimacion`)
 UNION 
(SELECT idOT, SUM(`horasintermedia`.`Horas`) AS `FIELD_1`,
        SUM(`horasintermedia`.`HorasX`) AS `FIELD_2` 
        FROM `horasintermedia` ) 
 UNION 
 (SELECT idOT, SUM(`horasacabado`.`Horas`) AS `FIELD_1`, 
         SUM(`horasacabado`.`HorasX`) AS `FIELD_2` 
         FROM `horasacabado`) 
  UNION 
 (SELECT idOT,SUM(`horascdot`.`Horas`) AS `FIELD_1`, 
         SUM(`horascdot`.`HorasX`) AS `FIELD_2` 
         FROM `horascdot` ) 
  UNION 
 (SELECT idOT,SUM(`horasotros`.`Horas`) AS `FIELD_1`, 
         SUM(`horasotros`.`HorasX`) AS `FIELD_2` 
         FROM `horasotros` ) 
 ) AS prueba
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estas haciendo es  partir dentro del `FROM ( ... )` es una subconsulta. A los efectos prácticos de tu pregunta no hay ninguna diferencia con cualquier otra tablas física. Por lo que nada te impide agregar el `JOIN` con otra tabla:

```
SELECT  prueba.idOT, 
    SUM(prueba.FIELD_1),
    SUM(prueba.FIELD_2), 
    OT.CampodeOtraTabla
    FROM    (   
        ...
        ) AS prueba
        LEFT JOIN OtraTabla OT
            ON OT.idOT = prueba.idOT
```

Lo importante es no olvidar definir un alias para cada tabla y usarlos apropiadamente en cada columna.